# Access Google Cloud Filestore over IP address or Internet

Tags: google-cloud-filestore

Can you access a Google Cloud Filestore outside the internal network, meaning to access it as an NFS with publicly accessible IP address or endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

No, the only way to access to Google Cloud Filestore via external IP is using a Compute Engine instance. but you can't use it as a NFS with publicly accessible IP. But, you can open a Feature Request, I'm sure that the Filestore engineering team will consider this feature.